# highchart js, tickinterval of 2 years(odd years) in x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to start the x-axis from 2005 with a tickinterval of 2 years which should give 2005, 2007, 2009 and so on as a result in the x-axis.

```
tickInterval: Date.UTC(2007, 1, 1) - Date.UTC(2005, 1, 1)
```

this should give odd dates right?

https://jsfiddle.net/nikbaidya0346/LLExL/6119/

Answer (score 0):

You define min/max values as even years, so tickInterval is calculated from there. Use the [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) to extract position of all ticks from processedXData, then filter them by checking current year. To do that use new Date() and getFullYear() functions.

```
         tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
            var each = Highcharts.each,
                points = this.series[0].processedXData,
              ticks = [],
              date ;
            each(points, function(d, i) {
              date = new Date(d);

              if(date.getFullYear() % 2 === 1) {
                ticks.push(d);
              }
            });

            return ticks;
        },
```

Example

- https://jsfiddle.net/ykpj56ub/